# Sorting an Array of objects by localized description of a property that contains a number

Tags: ios, iphone, sorting, nsarray

I have this object that has a property called `nameEN` that is the name the object has in english. When this object is shown on the screen it is like this:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTable([myObject nameEN]);
```

In other words, the name is localized by using `NSLocalizedStringFromTable`.

Said that, I have a lot of these objects on an array and I want to sort that array by the localized name.

The problem is that the objects have names like `House 1`, `House 2` ... `House 10`, etc.

When I sort that using this code:

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(MyOBject *p1, MyOBject *p2){
NSString *name1 = NSLocalizedStringFromTable([p1 nameEN], @"MyTable", nil);
NSString *name2 = NSLocalizedStringFromTable([p2 nameEN], @"MyTable", nil);
    return [name1 localizedCompare:name2];
  }];
```

The order I get is `House 1`, `House 10`, `House 2`... 10 before 2, 20 before 3 and so one.

How do I sort this using `NSComparisonResult`?

Comment: You have to cut off the number, convert it to a `NSNumber` or `NSInteger` and sort by the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer: just change `localizedCompare:` with `localizedStandardCompare:` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding last whitespace with rangeOfCharacter method with NSBackwardsSearch option enabled. With this range you can divide your string and compare first part containing name separately from second part containing number.

Comment: thanks but I have found an easier way. See my answer.

Comment: Looks much better :)